Is there any information on attempts at finding algorithms that are asymptotically faster than the FFT for the Discrete Fourier Transform?
I found out some bounds on the Discrete Fourier Transform calculation on certain models of computation but nothing on attempts at finding algorithms asymptotically faster than the Cooley-Tukey FFT on the RAM model of computation lets say.
Lets define the Discrete Fourier Transform as follows:
Given a sequence $x_0,x_2..,x_{N-1}$ of $N$ complex numbers transform them into $X_0,..,X_{N-1}$ with: $$X_k = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x_n \cdot e^{-i2\pi \tfrac{k}{N}n}$$

Is there any information on attempts at finding algorithms
asymptotically faster than the FFT for the Discrete Fourier Transform?


There are theoretical foundations for sparse Fourier transforms that can outperform state of the art FFT implementations. However, the signal has to be extremely sparse compared to the FFT length in most cases to the point where it isn’t useful in most practical scenarios.

@Baddioes I am aware of some of the work on sparse Fourier transforms but I was wondering if there are any documented attempts at finding a linear time algorithm for the discrete fourier transform.

By "linear" do you mean $\mathcal{O}(n)$?

@Nicolaus: this will be hard to answer without constraining the problem somewhat (target length, prime lengths, sparsity in time and/or frequency, etc). Most optimizations are based on some assumptions about the data. Even the FFT isn't all that fast for prime length DFTs but it's hard to beat for powers of 2. For larger FFTs the difference between $O(n)$ vs $O(n\log_2(n))$ becomes small, so $O(n)$ isn't all that attractive and it comes down to what exactly $O()$ is.

@Baddioes Yes. Linear in the number of terms of the polynomial

@Hilmar What I had in mind is the constraining contained in the usual definition of the dft problem that is found in introductory algorithm books (along with the fft).

@Nicolaus: sorry, I don't understand what you are talking about. There are MANY different formulations of the DFT and without a specific reference which one you have in mind it's hard to figure out what constraints you are referring to. I suggest adding the specific definitions and constraints to your question, so we all can talk about the same thing.

There is the Winograd Fourier Transform (WDFT).  But it's a bitch to code.

What's the time complexity of WDFT?

Wikipedia sez it's $O(n)$.

Perhaps its linear in terms of one computational resource that it uses but not in all its required resources.
